# Gvim on Raspberry Pi Error - Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-popdown-delay after class was initialised

Tags: linux, vim, raspberry-pi2

I have a raspberry pi 2, and I have used:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gtk
```

to install gvim.
When I load gvim I get these errors:

> (gvim:4407): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property
>   GtkSettings::gtk-menu-bar-popup-delay after class was initialised
>
> (gvim:4407): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property
>   GtkSettings::gtk-label-select-on-focus after class was initialised
>
> (gvim:4407): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property
>   GtkSettings::gtk-button-images after class was initialised
>
> (gvim:4407): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property
>   GtkSettings::gtk-can-change-accels after class was initialised
>
> (gvim:4407): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property
>   GtkSettings::gtk-menu-popup-delay after class was initialised
>
> (gvim:4407): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property
>   GtkSettings::gtk-menu-popdown-delay after class was initialised

Can anyone advise me on why I'm getting these errors (- I'm very new to the RPi) and what this means for my gvim!

Thanks,
Hazel

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of summary of discussion on [xfce forum](http://xfce.10915.n7.nabble.com/Many-GTK-warnings-td43476.html) where they had similar problem:

*It seems like GTK and Vim having some troubles in communication. These warnings are presumably fixed in a newer GTK+.*

It may be distro relevant, try to ask on Raspberry Pi website, or on site of OS you are using. Those warnings don't mean much.

You can go around like this. Try to put this

```
alias gvim='gvim  2> /dev/null'
```

in your `~/.bashrc`. It should disable warnings.

Answer (score -1):

RPI website says to do this (and it works):
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome